# Installing NVIDIA GEFORCE 920 M on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS | Acer Aspire E Series

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, acer

I Bought Acer Aspire E15 E5-573G-39G8 (NX.MVMSI.045) Notebook last month back which has the below graphic cards

- 2GB DDR3 NVIDIA 920M
- Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics ( fallback i guess )

Currently , this system running the later one

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

As far as the operating system goes it was having Linpus Linux , i removed that and installed Ubuntu 15.10

To be very honest being a web developer , i am not very interested in NVIDIA Graphics but since this system got upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 LTS, My system has gotten very hangy and it just crashes if i open 4-5 videos at once!
By surfing i found that its a driver issue #NVIDIA Graphics

--> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221740

So, my simple question is what i do now ?

Should i install NVIDIA Driver and if yes how i am gonna do that ?